# Redirecting SSL without raising an alert

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

A client has an SSL certificate only for the www.site.com version of the domain, not site.com.

Redirecting for regular HTTP was not a problem via mod_rewrite.

However, this method seemed to fail for us for HTTPS.

We want to redirect https://site.com requests to https://www.site.com.

Can this be done without raising an invalid certificate warning in the browser, or getting a wildcard certificate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way.

The SSL transaction happens before any HTTP is sent, so the SSL warning will appear before any redirect can happen.

Actually, I don't believe a wildcard would work, either, since site.com and *.site.com are not the same.  You may want to consider [Subject Alternative Names](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm) on the certificate.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. Thank you for confirming it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See http://serverfault.com/a/367843/113375

Comment: @BenLessani-Sonassi The linked answer does not seem to cover how you can have a redirect occur when the certificate for the original site is not recognized by the browser.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that almost all CA's will provide a certificate that covers both the apex domain and www subdomain when purchased under the www subdomain variant.

Answer (score 0):

RapidSSL's Basic Certificate when purchased under

```
www.mydomain.com
```

also covers

```
domain.com
```

Whilst not wildcard, it does give you cover for the TLD and www subdomain.

Yes, you can redirect from a subdomain to another **without** an SSL error - we use this on many, many sites, just one example is:

https://www.theclientarea.info which redirects to https://sms-sagat.theclientarea.info

Without error.

A simple .htaccess rewrite will take care of it for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !On [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any type of movement between HTTPS subdomains will work without error or prompt, be it POST/GET/.htaccess redirect

The only time it becomes an issue, is if you are redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP - then it will prompt you.

Comment: Right, you're using Subject Alternative Names in the certificate.  The OP is going to need a new cert.

Comment: No, we're using 2 separate certs. But I was just saying that the cheapest SSL cert on the market does what he needs (support for TLD with/without www subdomain).