# Redirect HTTPS to another HTTPS site without warning

Tags: https, redirect

I have recently moved a site over to a new domain. The hosting stayed the same, just a new URL for the site.

I want https://oldsite.com to redirect to https://newsite.com.

I'm getting the Invalid Certificate warning. Is it possible to do this without getting the warning?

I've found this question and answer ([Redirecting SSL without raising an alert](https://serverfault.com/questions/367818/redirecting-ssl-without-raising-an-alert)), but it doesn't quite apply since I'm going from one domain to another and not to a subdomain.

Comment: or use a 301 redirect?

Comment: @djdomi that will work for HTTPS to HTTPS?

Answer (score 4):

Just install a TLS certificate for the name(s) which need them.

Yes, you have to keep using a TLS certificate for old names you're redirecting from.

Comment: Thank you, I've never heard of that. Is it different than an SSL? Would it work on  GoDaddy host/DNS?

Comment: @GhostEcho TLS superseded SSL more than a decade ago. It's all we use anymore. But some people with lots of gray hair still call them "SSL certificates".

Comment: Ok. There is an SSL installed for the old site, would I need to rekey it to support the new domain? The GoDaddy chat is telling me "the ssl needs the domain which is hosted on the domain". She is saying HTTPS to HTTPS is not possible.

Comment: @GhostEcho Yes, you need certificates for every name you use, old and new.

Comment: When I install the certificate, it removes another certificate. Both domains are listed in the same FQDNs 'section' within cPanel.

Comment: would you be available for a chat to help me?

Comment: @GhostEcho I think you're going to need cPanel support. That is [not something we do here](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094/126632).

Comment: either use lets encrypt or play the rules that admin panels are not supported